# Additional information: ORA-00917: missing comma

Tags: c#, oracle

I am kinda lost, I dont know what to try next.

```
com.CommandText =@"insert into TDESADV_H_T (spplr_mailbox,message_id,asn_no,TO_DATE('message_date', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI'))"
                    + " VALUES(:spplr_mailbox,:message_id,:asn_no,:message_date)";
```

It is definetly on the message date. The query recieves:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("message_date", edi.MESSAGE_SEND_DATE);
```

which is: 2017/10/23 18:01. I am not sure what is wrong

Comment: Please look through the fields you're trying to insert into, it seems you have a `TO_DATE` expression in the *field list*, this is definitely incorrect syntax. It should be `INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES (values)` and you have `INSERT INTO table (fields, TO_DATE(...)) ...`

Comment: Where should I specify the oracle type, while I am trying to insert from c# app please?

Comment: I don't know what your comment means, the problem here is completely in the SQL, not in the parameters, your SQL has a TO_DATE expression in the list of fields, where it isn't allowed, which is why Oracle is complaining.

Comment: Why do you even have TO_DATE at all? What type is the `message_date` field in the database?

Comment: Yes I have to, I read those variables from XML in c# and the query wont accept date as string without that function. Maybe I should have stated that earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LasseVågsætherKarlsen navigated me. I was trying to use TO_DATE for column name. All I had to do was to use the function in values (). Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: OK, but it somehow feels wrong to me that you're using an Oracle function to manually convert data coming from .NET.  Perhaps you can find a way to let the driver do this for you, and then you could just bind a parameter without the function call.

Answer (score 2):

`TO_DATE('message_date', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI')` in `INSERT` statement should be a column name rather. That's what it's complaining about

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL syntax is off, and the insert should look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TDESADV_H_T (spplr_mailbox, message_id, asn_no, message_date)
VALUES (:spplr_mailbox, :message_id, :asn_no, :message_date);
```

Regarding your call to `TO_DATE`, if that happens at all, it should be when you bind the parameter in your C# code.  You should ideally be able to bind a C# type which the API can automatically marshall over to the `message_date` column, so that call to `TO_DATE` might not even be needed.

Comment: You absolutely can make function calls inside a VALUES clause.

Comment: @kfinity Why did I think that wasn't possible.  I seem to recall in MySQL that it can't really be done.